# dlopen() search path

Tags: c, linux, dlopen

is there a way to find out programmatically which paths are searched by dlopen() for shared objects? I always thought dlopen() would only look in /lib and /usr/lib but now I've seen that on Linux Mint several core components like libglib-2.0.so are in a wholly different folders, namely in /rofs/lib/i386-gnu-linux and some others. Is there a way to get to know all these paths that dlopen() will search through for a shared object? I already checked the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH but it's not defined at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

look at the `ldconfig` man page, and the file: `/etc/ld.so.conf`

Answer (score 6):

In addition of the `ld.so.conf` hint:

If you want to ensure that a specific library is `dlopen`-ed, pass a path to `dlopen`, e.g. `dlopen("/some/path/to/lib.so",  RTLD_LOCAL)` or maybe `dlopen("./lib.so",  RTLD_LOCAL)` but not  `dlopen("lib.so",  RTLD_LOCAL)`

If on Linux, read the `man` page [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)