# how to add operation to tensorflow(tutorial)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to add my own operation to tensorflow.
so I read https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op#use_the_op_in_python.
And then I tried to add new operation but it doesn't work.
error massage: tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: dlopen(zero_out.so, 6): image not found

I put this source code to tensorflow/tensorflow/core/user_ops naming zero_out.cc.

```
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/shape_inference.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h"
using namespace tensorflow;
REGISTER_OP("ZeroOut")
    .Input("to_zero: int32")
    .Output("zeroed: int32")
    .SetShapeFn([](::tensorflow::shape_inference::InferenceContext* c) {
      c->set_output(0, c->input(0));
      return Status::OK();
    });

class ZeroOutOp : public OpKernel {
 public:
  explicit ZeroOutOp(OpKernelConstruction* context) : OpKernel(context) {}
  void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {
    // Grab the input tensor
    const Tensor& input_tensor = context->input(0);
    auto input = input_tensor.flat<int32>();
    // Create an output tensor
    Tensor* output_tensor = NULL;
    OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_output(0, input_tensor.shape(),
                                                     &output_tensor));
    auto output = output_tensor->flat<int32>();
"zero_out.cc" 35L, 1286C

class ZeroOutOp : public OpKernel {
 public:
  explicit ZeroOutOp(OpKernelConstruction* context) : OpKernel(context) {}
  void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {
    // Grab the input tensor
    const Tensor& input_tensor = context->input(0);
    auto input = input_tensor.flat<int32>();
    // Create an output tensor
    Tensor* output_tensor = NULL;
    OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_output(0, input_tensor.shape(),
                                                     &output_tensor));
    auto output = output_tensor->flat<int32>();
    // Set all but the first element of the output tensor to 0.
    const int N = input.size();
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
      output(i) = 0;
    }
    // Preserve the first input value if possible.
    if (N > 0) output(0) = input(0);
  }
};

REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("ZeroOut").Device(DEVICE_CPU), ZeroOutOp);
```

I just write same thing with tutorial.
and then, I made BUILD file with same path.(tensorflow/tensorflow/core/user_ops)

```
load("//tensorflow:tensorflow.bzl", "tf_custom_op_library")

tf_custom_op_library(
    name = "zero_out.so",
    srcs = ["zero_out.cc"],
)
```

then, in terminal(path ~/tensorflow) I typped bazel build command.

```
bazel build --config opt //tensorflow/core/user_ops:zero_out.so
```

And I tried to run my code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
zero_out_module = tf.load_op_library('zero_out.so')
with tf.Session(''):
  zero_out_module.zero_out([[1, 2], [3, 4]]).eval()
```

But only have error massage.

```
error massage: tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: dlopen(zero_out.so, 6): image not found
```

I want to know what's wrong.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: The error is about Python being unable to locate `zero_out.so`. Did you run the code with Bazel or simply from the terminal? I think you should run it from Bazel so it makes the compiled library available to Python.

Comment: I want to just import tensorflow and run my operation. then should I add bazel commend to make available to Python? I can't find it from tutorial..

Comment: Try running it with Bazel (`py_binary` rule with dependency on your `tf_custom_op_library`) first to make sure it's compiled properly. Afterwards, you can find a way to install that `zero_out.so` in your system so it can be found by plain Python (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193640/dlopen-search-path)).

Comment: ok I'll try thank you!

Comment: try to find the library find . -iname zero_out.so and make sure is in the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH on mac or LD_LIBRAY_PATH if on linux

Comment: I typped find / -iname zero_out.so. and output is /private/var/tmp/_bazel_buginus/f61592e85e27d606ef62b0b094738cf0/execroot/tensorflow/bazel-out/local-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/user_ops/_objs/zero_out.so
/private/var/tmp/_bazel_buginus/f61592e85e27d606ef62b0b094738cf0/execroot/tensorflow/bazel-out/local-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/user_ops/zero_out.so
/private/var/tmp/_bazel_buginus/f61592e85e27d606ef62b0b094738cf0/execroot/tensorflow/bazel-out/local-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/user_ops/zero_out.so.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/user_ops/zero_out.so.
can you tell me what should I